# Powershell script terminates before output is displayed

Tags: powershell

When executing the below script, the output will be displayed very briefly as the script is closing. I am looking for a way to have the script pause after the output.

```
function Get-Hostname() {
    $IP_Address = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the target IP Address'
    [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress("$IP_Address")
}

function Exit-Application() {
    Read-Host "Press Enter to Exit Application"
    exit
}

Get-Hostname
Exit-Application
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this happens, but you can fix it by changing

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress("$IP_Address")
```

To:

```
Write-Output $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($IP_Address))
```

and piping the output of the function.

```
Get-Hostname | ft
```

Using `Write-Output` preserves the object being returned from the function which you can work with or in this instance process the function output using `Format-Table` (`ft`).

You can check the object type being returned with `(Get-Hostname).getType() | ft -autosize`

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name        BaseType     
-------- -------- ----        --------     
True     False    IPHostEntry System.Object
```

The full code:

```
function Get-Hostname {
    $IP_Address = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the target IP Address'
    Write-Output $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress("$IP_Address"))
}

function Exit-Application {
    Read-Host "Press Enter to Exit Application"
    exit
}

Get-Hostname | ft
Exit-Application
```

Comment: This worked too, thanks!

Comment: `Write-Output` makes no difference here - what matter is the explicit use of `ft` (`Format-Table`), which forces synchronous output.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `Get-Hostname` function outputs the object to the console before you call `Exit-Application`, Try something like this:

```
function Get-Hostname() {
    $IP_Address = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the target IP Address'
    [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress("$IP_Address") | Format-Table -AutoSize
}

function Exit-Application() {
    Read-Host "Press Enter to Exit Application"
    exit
}

Get-Hostname
Exit-Application
```

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like a read host prompt

```
  Read-Host -Prompt 'Press any key to close'
    exit
```

Comment: Same output happens, Exit is prompted before output is displayed.

Comment: @NickB: `Read-Host` is what the OP is using, and it surfaces the problem.